# How do I animate a NSLayoutConstraint in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, nslayoutconstraint

I would like to animate an UIImageView. I declared a `NSLayoutConstraint` in `viewDidLoad` and used this code:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1) {
    myConstraint.constant = 100
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Why doesn't my image move?

Comment: Using the code sample in your question as-is!

Answer (score 46, accepted):

By the time you hit `viewDidLoad`, the constraints engine has not yet been applied and the starting location of the views has not yet been established. So, feel free to add the original constraints in `viewDidLoad`, but you will want to defer the `animateWithDuration` until later in the process (e.g. `viewDidAppear`).

---

For example, let's assume you have some constraint that you added in Interface Builder (IB). You can add an`@IBOutlet` reference to it by <kbd>control</kbd>-dragging from the constraint in the document outline in the left panel in Interface Builder down to the assistant editor:

[image]

Now that you have a reference to that constraint, you can now programmatically alter the `constant` value for that constraint (but, again, do this in `viewDidAppear`, not `viewDidLoad`, if you want to see this animated when the view is presented):

```
@IBOutlet weak var topConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    topConstraint.constant = 100
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 2) {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

The process is the same for programmatically created constraints. Just save a reference to the constraint and then in `viewDidAppear` update the `constant` and then animate the call to `layoutIfNeeded()`.

Comment: If it is possible for you then please post some code with the explanations...Thanks by the way for your response..

Comment: @iCrunCher - See revised answer.

Comment: Interesting. I usually put **both** the assignment of the constant's new value **and** the call to `layoutIfNeeded()` inside the animation block (I got it from some other answer here), and it works (back then when we used `frame` to animate a view's position, we set it inside the animation block too -and `layoutIfNeeded()` wasn't needed). **I wonder why this works too.**

Comment: You only need `layoutIfNeeded` inside the animation block, because that forces the auto layout engine to recalculate the `frame`, and that's what we're animating. Having said that, like you, I also tend to put the modification of the constraint in that block as I think that makes the functional intent of the animation more clear, IMHO. But I left the changing of the constraint outside of the animation block in this example to make clear, technically, what one needs to animate the result of changing constraints.

Comment: swift 3 -> UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }

Answer (score 10):

Please set your constraint in viewDidAppear and try below correction

```
myConstant = 100
myConstraint.constant = myConstant
UIView.animateWithDuration(1, animations: {
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}, completion: {finished in })
```