# How to animate a UIView that has constraints?

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiview

I have two `UIViews` I would like to animate on screen and off. Both should start positioned off screen. The top animates downward, bottom upward. Without constraints it works as expected. But with, the `UIViews` are visible at app launch (with a slight animation that is visible). They do animate off screen though.

For the top `UIView`, I have a Leading Space, Trailing Space, Top Space, and Height.

For the bottom `UIView`, I have a Leading Space, Trailing Space, Bottom Space, and Height.

How should I adjust my code and/or constraints to get the desired animation?

Here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self animateViewsIn];
}

- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];

    self.topView.frame = CGRectMake(16.0, -self.topView.frame.size.height, self.topView.frame.size.width, self.topView.frame.size.height);

    self.bottomView.frame = CGRectMake(16.0, self.view.bounds.size.height, self.bottomView.frame.size.width, self.bottomView.frame.size.height);
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)animateViewsIn {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                      delay:1.0
                    options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                 animations:^{
                     self.topView.frame = CGRectMake(16.0, 
    self.topView.frame.size.height/8.0, self.topView.frame.size.width, 
    self.topView.frame.size.height);
                     self.bottomView.frame = CGRectMake(16.0, (self.view.bounds.size.height-self.bottomView.frame.size.height)-20.0, self.bottomView.frame.size.width, self.bottomView.frame.size.height);
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     NSLog(@"Done!");
                 }];
}

- (IBAction)animateViewsOut:(id)sender {
    CGRect basketTopFrame = self.topView.frame;
    basketTopFrame.origin.y = -basketTopFrame.size.height;

    CGRect basketBottomFrame = self.bottomView.frame;
    basketBottomFrame.origin.y = self.view.bounds.size.height;


    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                      delay:1.0
                    options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                 animations:^{
                     [self.view layoutIfNeeded];

                     self.topView.frame = basketTopFrame;
                     self.bottomView.frame = basketBottomFrame;
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     NSLog(@"Done!");
                 }];
}
```

Comment: When using constraints, you should not be adjusting frames. You should be modifying the `constant` property of the constraint (or deactivinging one constraint and activating another). Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/28329399/1271826 (tho, admittedly Swift answer; the idea is identical in Objective-C). Or here is Objective-C answer that illustrates the animation of constraints: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14190042/1271826.

Comment: Thank you Rob. I have added the constraints connected via IBOutlet and using the constant to animate them, but how do I start the UIViews off-screen?

Comment: leftConstraint.constant - 320. is example how to start offscreen.

Answer (score 1):

When using constraints, you should not be adjusting frames. You should be modifying the `constant` property of the constraint (or deactivinging one constraint and activating another).

Here's an example of animating the top view in from the top, assuming you added a `@IBOutlet` called `topConstraint` to the top constraint of the view `topView`:

In Objective-C:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    self.topConstraint.constant = -self.topView.frame.size.height;  // or whatever you want
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:1 options:0 animations:^{
        self.topConstraint.constant = 0;
        [self.topView layoutIfNeeded];
    } completion:nil];
}
```

In Swift:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    topConstraint.constant = -topView.frame.height  // or whatever you want
    view.layoutIfNeeded()
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 1, animations: {
        topConstraint.constant = 0
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    })
}
```